# NSFetchedResultsController with different sort descriptors by section?

Tags: core-data

I have an NSFetchedResultsController that I has the first sorting descriptor of the sort descriptors array as the same as the sectionNameKeyPath, thus giving me different sections. But I want the second sort descriptor to be different pr section. Is there a good way to do this without me having to push the data into arrays that I then sort again?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0):

You already suggested using different arrays internally for each section.  That's not a bad  approach, because in reality you only have to worry about a mapping between index paths of the displayed objects and the real objects.

In other words, you know the small number of items the table view is displaying because it asks the controller for those.  You don't have to give it back the items directly from the array of fetched results in the FRC.

Take the index path, figure out which section is being requested, and grab your pre-sorted rows for that section.  Since the data is pretty small, you may get away with sorting them on the fly as they are requested.

Another method is to just add another attribute to the data model.  This attribute represents the sort order within the section, and you can set it to whatever values you want, since the whole array will be sorted first by section, then by that attribute.

Also, you may find it easier to use a proxy object as a front-end to the fetched results controller.  Similar to the "multiple arrays" approach, you just use a proxy object that applies unique sort descriptors on each section when that section is requested by the table view, and returns the objects in its own sorted order.